# If I use the Shapechange spell to turn into a phoenix, can I use its legendary resistances to pass Con saves to maintain concentration?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, concentration

I've been trying to make use of the Shapechange spell as a 9th-level spell with a Druid class, but concentration seems to be a major issue.

Say I transform into a Phoenix, can I use its 3 Legendary Resistances to automatically succeed in a damaging saving throw three times to prolong the form?

This would make Shapechange viable for melee characters for at least a slightly longer period than a single turn.

Comment: We've marked your question as a dupe because we think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find those. If those questions doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 0):

**Legendary Resistances are available to you while Shape Changed**

The appropriate part of the spell description says:

> Your game Statistics are replaced by the Statistics of the chosen creature, though you retain your Alignment and Intelligence, Wisdom, and Charisma scores You also retain all of your skill and saving throw Proficiencies, in addition to gaining those of the creature, If the creature has the same proficiency as you, and the bonus listed in its Statistics is higher than yours, use the creature's bonus in place of yours. You can't use any legendary Actions or Lair Actions of the new form.

Legendary resistances are not mentioned anywhere as being unavailable or altered in anyway.

This is backed up by a (unofficial Tweet) tweet from [Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/935211567867600896):

> So you get Legendary Resistances?...

> No rule says you don’t.